# Making a resource (like a pdf) available only if its URL is called from a certain page

Tags: html, .htaccess, pdf

I have a pdf file (myFile.pdf) and an HTML page (myPage.html) which contains the following markup:

```
 <a href='myFile.pdf'>Click here to view PDF</a>
```

Is there a way to make so that the pdf is ONLY reachable when clicking on the link contained in myPage.html and in all the other cases the user gets a redirect to myPage.html ? It's different from hotlinking because it should also prevent direct accessing the URL by typing the address of the PDF. The most similar problem I found so far is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124109/protect-pdf-docs-from-being-directly-accessed-in-url) but it does not fully apply to this particular case.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.domain\.com/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myPage.html
RewriteRule .*\.pdf - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.domain\.com/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myPage.html
RewriteRule .*\.pdf /your_page [R,L]
```